# Echo post title in array

Tags: php

I am using Imbalance 2 theme from wpshower.  I want to add alt and title tags so they show up in the loop on the homepage.  My title and alt tags are the same as the post title...  so, I want to echo the post title in the array.  I have been playing around but can't seem to figure it out.  I'm a newbee to php, so all and any help will be appreciated. Below is the code from my theme...  What do I need to put inside of the '' to echo the post title?  Thanks in advance...

```
<a class="transparent" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('homepage-thumb', array('alt' => '', 'title' => '')) ?></a>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Wordpress, or wpshower. But the general format would be <?php echo post=>title; ?>. As the 'title' is an attribute of 'post'. Assuming it's stored like that.. You should try and show us more of your code, but going on the few characters you're showing I'd say post=>title should do the trick.

Comment: Hi Kevin..  the site is RKR.me ...  I have added the code inside of the '' that you suggested. If you look at the homepage and hover over the image or look at the source, it only shows the code but does not actually echo the post title.   What did i do wrong?

Comment: Could you please show me the functions you're using? the_permalink() and the_post_thumbnail(). It looks like they're returning the <?php echo ?> part as a string instead of it's echo value

Comment: On second thought, try this: the_post_thumbnail('homepage-thumb', array('alt' => '', 'title' => <?php echo post=>title?>)). the 'post' being the variable that stores the post/product data

Comment: I get a php error...  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home3/yokohama/public_html/rkr.me/wp-content/themes/imbalance2/loop.php on line 26

Comment: Do you have any experience using PHP? If not, I suggest trying to follow some tutorials en reading up on it first. I can't help without seeing more code, so I know how it's formatted.

Comment: Kevin, the syntax to access an object property is this: $post->title, not post=>title. Also, the $post global will not be available unless you use global $post; prior to using it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<a class="transparent" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('homepage-thumb', array('alt' => get_the_title(), 'title' => get_the_title())) ?>
</a>
```